# Why does using upper() in two different places give different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase

I tried these codes to sort out vowels and consonants. But I discovered that in the first code I get wrong output while the second one is correct. What are the differences?

```
#First code
a = input()

if ord(a.upper()) in range(65, 91):

    if a in 'AEIOU':

        print('Vowel')

    else:

        print('Consonant')

else:

    print('Nothing')
```

```
#Second code
a = input().upper()

if ord(a) in range(65, 91):

    if a in 'AEIOU':

        print('Vowel')

    else:

        print('Consonant')

else:

    print('Nothing')
```

Comment: I have explained . check my answer

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 2):

The first version should read:
`if a.upper() in 'AEIOU':`
... otherwise a lower case input letter will still be lower case in this comparison and fail.

On a side note, that ord/range business should be replaced with `a.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
if ord(a.upper()) in range(65, 91):
    if a.upper() in 'AEIOU':
       print('Vowel')
    else:
        print('Consonant')
else:
    print('Nothing')
```

The first program must be like this. You require to compare `a.upper()` with 'AEIOU' for correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#First code
a = input()
a = a.upper()

if ord(a) in range(65, 91):

    if a in 'AEIOU':

        print('Vowel')

    else:

        print('Consonant')

else:

    print('Nothing')
```

or:

```
#First code

a = input()

if ord(a.upper()) in range(65, 91):

    if a.upper() in 'AEIOU':

        print('Vowel')

    else:

        print('Consonant')

else:

    print('Nothing')
```

The string variable is immutable. As a result, you should always use upper () to capitalize, or use a = a.upper ().

Answer (score -1):

In the first case you are comparing the lower case value of the input(might be) which will not match and `'Consonant'` in printed as part of the else block.

```
#First code

a = input()

if ord(a.upper()) in range(65, 91):

    if a in 'AEIOU': #here a is in lower case

        print('Vowel')
```

Interesting thing is if you enter `A` as your input both of the code blocks will produce same result.

but in 2nd case you are converting the input value to uppercase in the beginning before comparing in the `If` block

```
#Second code
a = input().upper()

if ord(a) in range(65, 91):

    if a in 'AEIOU': #here it is in uppercase

        print('Vowel')
```

That is why 'Vowel' is printed as part of the `If` block.

Comment: They give the `upper`-ed string to `ord` in both versions.

Comment: it is just scope of a which differ, in code 1, `a.upper()` scope is inside the `if` statement only, after that it is same as input a, while in code 2, a scope made throughout the program